# How to attach an eventhandler from a customcontrol to its parent usercontrol close event?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, custom-controls

I have been unable to find an answer to this. I have a long series of usercontrols, each creating one or more usercontrol children. The last usercontrol in the series creates a custom control that uses unmanaged code.

I need the custom control to be made aware of the user closing its parent user control window when the upper right "X" is clicked. This so as to properly dispose of the unmanaged code.

The essential XAML is:

```
 <UserControl x:Class="Nova5.UI.Views.Ink.InkEditorView"
      <!--DataContext in InkEditorViewModel.cs-->
      <wc:CustomInkCanvas x:Name="myInkCanvas"
                          Vocabulary="{Binding Vocabulary, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                          Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" 
                          WordPad="{Binding WordPad, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                          CloseCharacterPads ="{Binding CloseCharacterPads}"/>
</UserControl>
```

Assuming that the usercontrol itself can be made aware of the closing event from its parent usercontrol, how can I attach a method from the custom control wc:CustomInkCanvas to the closing event of its parent usercontrol?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the answer I was really hoping for, but this works when placed in the customInkCanvas constructor:

```
  Unloaded += new RoutedEventHandler(CustomInkCanvas_Unloaded);
```

Any better ideas?